# Color Inside an Array

Tags: color, arrays

I am using the packages `amsmath` and `color`.

The following works to color an entire array blue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}

\[
{\color{blue}
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 1\\
 -3
\end{array}
\right)
}
\]

\end{document}
```

If I just want the numbers to be blue, I can move the `\color` inside the parens:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}

\[
\left(
{\color{blue}
\begin{array}{c}
 1\\
 -3
\end{array}
}
\right)
\]

\end{document}
```

That works. However, if I move the `\color` inside the array, it does not work. The two errors are

> Missing } inserted

and

> Extra }, or forgotten $.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}

\[
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
{\color{blue}
 1\\
 -3
 }
\end{array}
\right)
\]

\end{document}
```

Why does that not work?

Comment: remove grouping { } inside array and you'll see.

Comment: In `array` environment each column is group (in this case each raw) so you have error 1) `\begingroup{ color{blue} 1\endgroup` error 2 `\begingroup 3}\endgroup`

Comment: @touhami, When I remove grouping inside the array, only the 1 gets colored blue, not the -3. What is that supposed to be indicative of?

Comment: each cell is a group, you can not start a group in one cell and end it in another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Color each cell:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor,array}

\begin{document}

\[
\left(
\begin{array}{@{}>{\color{blue}}c@{}}
 1\\
 -3
\end{array}
\right)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]